# How to hide Status Bar without change position of app screen

Tags: react-native, expo, statusbar

I use react native to develop my app. I want to show Image full screen but my code let Screen of my app change position when status bar hidden.

```
const myApp = () => {
  const [hiddenStatusBar, setHiddenStatusBar] = useState()
  const onClickImage = useCallback(() => {
    if (hiddenStatusBar) {
        setHiddenStatusBar(false)
    } else {
        setHiddenStatusBar(true)
    }
   }, [hiddenStatusBar])
  return(
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Pressable onPress={onClickImage}>
        <Image source={{ uri: item?.uri }}
          style={{ width: mobileWidth, height: mobileHeight }}
          contentFit="cover"
        />
      </Pressable>
      <StatusBar hidden={hiddenStatusBar} animated={true} />
    </View>
   )
  }
```

What i want:

[image]

But my code output:

[image]

Can someone help me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`StatusBarManager.HEIGHT` will return the fixed height of the status bar.

1. `top: hiddenStatusBar ? 0 : -StatusBarManager.HEIGHT`
   When the status bar is visible, the `ImageBackground` is shifted to the top by an offset equal to the status bar height. This maintains the image ratio to be the same both before and after.
2. StatusBar shouldn't be wrapped as a child component; instead, it should be moved to the top of the code.

With these two fixes, the resizing flicker issue gets hidden, as the image ratio is maintained in both the states.

```
import {
      StyleSheet,
      Pressable,
      View,
      StatusBar,
      useWindowDimensions,
      ImageBackground,
      NativeModules,
    } from 'react-native';
    import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
    
    const { StatusBarManager } = NativeModules;
    
    export default function App() {
      const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
      const [hiddenStatusBar, setHiddenStatusBar] = useState();
    
      const onClickImage = useCallback(() => {
        if (hiddenStatusBar) {
          setHiddenStatusBar(false);
        } else {
          setHiddenStatusBar(true);
        }
      }, [hiddenStatusBar]);
    
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar hidden={hiddenStatusBar} animated={true} />
          <ImageBackground
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: hiddenStatusBar ? 0 : -StatusBarManager.HEIGHT,
              width,
              height,
            }}
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{ uri: 'https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Pressable
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  opacity: 0,
                }}
                onPress={onClickImage}
              />
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
        </>
      );
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).